# How to grant Custom Object Read Write Permission to Standard User?

Tags: apex, custom-object

I have created a custom object and I need that `Standard user profile` to use that object. However, I can't see the read write permission on that object.

How can i achieve that functionality?

Answer (score 1):

1. Check if the object is deployed.
2. After the new layout changes there is a section called object settings where you can control tab visibility, object CRUD etc...

In the search box when you go to setup-- manage user-- profile just type the custom object name abd you can change all custom object visibility

Comment: I got the solution, you can grant the access to specific user through permission set assignment. Set up - Manage User - Permission sets - Create new Permission set - select User License whom you want to assign the permission - from User Detail Page assign the permission set to User.

Comment: @rao - the question was regarding standard profiles - custom objects don't appear on these (with the exception of system administrator) since the Spring 10 release.

Comment: opps forgot to notice the standard profile, will be more observant in the future!!!